# Files in ignored folder still show in GitHub Desktop

Tags: github

I've just added a brand new local repository using `GitHub Desktop`. There are folders I don't want to commit, so I added these to `.gitignore` as follows:

```
cache/*.*
```

Now the problem is that the files within the ignored folder still show up.

How can I automatically get rid of these files? I can check all the checkboxes manually, right click and choose `ignore` but that would be a lot of work.

Or should I publish these files hoping they'll get ignored and won't show up in the future?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470572/gitignore-ignore-any-bin-directory

Answer (score 0):

.gitignore just keeps the files from being tracked or checked in to the remote repository. It doesn't make them invisible.